Unreal ue5-main compile from source
Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.12.3
with .NET Framework 4.809037.
Following these instructions
https://dev.epicgames.com/documentation/en-us/unreal-engine/building-unreal-engine-from-source?application_version=5.4
After several hours and a partially complete compile Visual Studio quits with the following error

The command "....\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="UnrealEditor
Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development
-Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild -architecture=x64" exited with code 6.

The preceding line in the Output window is

Failed to produce item:
C:\Users\foo\source\UnrealEngine\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealEditor-BuildSettings.dll

Can any visual studio or C++ wizards suggest next troubleshooting steps?

As a person who knows nothing of unreal-engine the first thing I would do is look for additional information about the error in a build log. If there is none I would figure out what exit code 6 means. And if it takes opening up build.bat in Notepad++ to look I would do that.

Maybe check that your build scripts have write permissions to all locations where they want to write files..

Because you've tagged with UE5, the same error message is mentioned in Build.bat error code 6 in the Unreal Engine 5

"The preceding line in the Output window is" -- And what's before that? And before that? You want the first error reported, not the reports of things that failed as consequences of that error.

"Following these instructions [link]" -- Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained, not relying on external links for key information. If that is not practical, the footer of the linked page might be useful: "Ask questions and help your peers Developer Forums"
